# using django-filer, "Must be a 'image' instance"

Tags: python, django, upload

I am working with filer on a project. I have a big sized documents with data in it and a file with images that is related to that data. Now I need to get all these on my system and some how connect them together.

I am using import-export to upload the data. So I am thinking of using the filer import script to mass upload the images into a folder. But then how to relate the record to that image without using the filer GUI in the admin system. If I did use that, would it mean going through every record and adding a image one by one.

When I try and upload anything into the image column I got the error shown below in the image.

How can I get around this issue?

[image: Error i get when uploading to the image column.]

Comment: Any update on this? facing same issue.

Comment: Does anyone knows answer to this question?